# How do I know if a function is tail recursive in F#

Tags: f#, recursion, tail-recursion, tail-call-optimization

I wrote the follwing function:

```
let str2lst str =
    let rec f s acc =
      match s with
        | "" -> acc
        | _  -> f (s.Substring 1) (s.[0]::acc)
    f str []
```

How can I know if the F# compiler turned it into a loop? Is there a way to find out without using Reflector (I have no experience with Reflector and I Don't know C#)?

Edit: Also, is it possible to write a tail recursive function without using an inner function, or is it necessary for the loop to reside in?

Also, Is there a function in F# std lib to run a given function a number of times, each time giving it the last output as input? Lets say I have a string, I want to run a function over the string then run it again over the resultant string and so on...

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809683/is-my-rec-function-tail-recursive

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Edit: Since F# 8 there is a way with the `[<TailCall>]` attribute, see this answer:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/77532717/969070

*Original answer:*

Unfortunately there is no trivial way.

It is not too hard to read the source code and use the types and determine whether something is a tail call by inspection (is it 'the last thing', and not in a 'try' block), but people second-guess themselves and make mistakes.  There's no simple automated way (other than e.g. inspecting the generated code).

Of course, you can just try your function on a large piece of test data and see if it blows up or not.

The F# compiler will generate .tail IL instructions for all tail calls (unless the compiler flags to turn them off is used - used for when you want to keep stack frames for debugging), with the exception that directly tail-recursive functions will be optimized into loops.  (EDIT: I think nowadays the F# compiler also fails to emit .tail in cases where it can prove there are no recursive loops through this call site; this is an optimization given that the .tail opcode is a little slower on many platforms.)

'tailcall' is a reserved keyword, with the idea that a future version of F# may allow you to write e.g.

```
tailcall func args
```

and then get a warning/error if it's not a tail call.

Only functions that are not naturally tail-recursive (and thus need an extra accumulator parameter) will 'force' you into the 'inner function' idiom.

Here's a code sample of what you asked:

```
let rec nTimes n f x =
    if n = 0 then
        x
    else
        nTimes (n-1) f (f x)

let r = nTimes 3 (fun s -> s ^ " is a rose") "A rose"
printfn "%s" r
```

Comment: "tailcall" is interesting, as it has you specify the site of call instead of what may be a more useful "tailrec" declaration on the whole function.  Can you have a "partially tail-recursive" function?

Comment: @StephenSwensen You absolutely can. Control flow branches could lead to an alternative between a tail call and a call that isn't a tail call, and you may only want to check the one that actually is a tail call at compile time. `let rec f x = if x > 0 then f(1+x) else 0 + f(1+x)` illustrates the concept, although obviously it wouldn't terminate.

Answer (score 4):

[The compiler can check this for you, as of F# 8](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-fsharp-8/#tailcall-attribute)! Mark the function with `TailCallAttribute`, and you'll get a warning if you provide an implementation that isn't tail recursive.

For example, this code:

```ml
[<TailCall>]
let rec fibNaive n =
    if n <= 1 then n
    else fibNaive (n - 1) + fibNaive (n - 2)
```

emits two instances of `Warning FS3569 : The member or function 'fibNaive' has the 'TailCallAttribute' attribute, but is not being used in a tail recursive way.` (one for each recursive call)

While this code emits no warnings:

```ml
[<TailCall>]
let fibFast n =
    let rec fibFast x y n =
        match n with
        | _ when n < 1 -> x
        | 1 -> y
        | _ -> fibFast y (x + y) (n - 1)
    fibFast 0 1 n
```

For bonus points, it can be a good idea to turn this into an error, by adding `<WarningsAsErrors>FS3569</WarningsAsErrors>` to your fsproj.

Answer (score 3):

I like the rule of thumb Paul Graham formulates in *On Lisp*: if there is **work left to do**, e.g. manipulating the recursive call output, then the call is not tail recursive.