# What's some simple F# code that generates the .tail IL instruction?

Tags: .net, f#, tail-recursion, tail-call-optimization

I'd like to see the `.tail` IL instruction, but the simple recursive functions using tail calls that I've been writing are apparently optimized into loops.  I'm actually guessing on this, as I'm not entirely sure what a loop looks like in Reflector.  I definitely don't see any `.tail` opcodes though.  I have "Generate tail calls" checked in my project's properties.  I've also tried both Debug and Release builds in Reflector.

The code I used is from [Programming F# by Chris Smith](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596153643), page 190:

```
let factorial x =
// Keep track of both x and an accumulator value (acc)
let rec tailRecursiveFactorial x acc =
    if x <= 1 then
        acc
    else
        tailRecursiveFactorial (x - 1) (acc * x)
tailRecursiveFactorial x 1
```

Can anyone suggest some simple F# code which will indeed generate `.tail`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mutually recursive functions should:

```
let rec even n = 
    if n = 0 then 
        true 
    else
        odd (n-1)
and odd n =
    if n = 1 then 
        true 
    else
        even (n-1)
```

(have not tried it just now).

EDIT

See also

[How do I know if a function is tail recursive in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806712/how-do-i-know-if-a-function-is-tail-recursive-in-f)

Comment: I've checked just now. Yes! it generates .tail.